# Different size photos using mysql and repeat statement

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to have a homepage which shows 12 different sized photos using 1 repeat statement (while, do, etc)

The database holds the photo name (name.jpg) and the hard coded path to the image folder are held in the main coding of the page.

When the images are uploaded, they are all the same size, but want to show them at different width and height sizes on the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it it possible, either by separate array were width/height stored for each photo, or you can go with random